# Remove IIS configuration setting using AppCmd without clearing the entire section

Tags: iis, configuration, appcmd

I am using the following **appcmd** to add an autoStartProvider to the list of **autoStartProviders**:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders /+"[name='MyAutoStartup',type='PreWarmCache, MyAssembly, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null']" /commit:apphost
```

Running the script for the first time, everything works correctly. But when running the script for the second time it complains that **"MyAutoStartup" already exists**. I know I can clear out the collection by using:

```
appcmd.exe clear config -section:system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders -commit:apphost
```

but that would **remove all keys**, not just MyAutoStart.

Is there a way to **only remove MyAutoStart** if it is present?

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting I found the following command worked:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders /-"[name='MyAutoStartup',type='PreWarmCache, MyAssembly, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null']" /commit:apphost
```

Basically it is replacing the "/+" with a "/-"